# Axon Framework: How to use state-stored aggregates

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am using spring boot with Axon 4.2.
I tried to use the state stored aggregates, I tried two ways but none non of them worked.

1., I tried exactly as you wrote here: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/state-stored-aggregates

My code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "szervezet")
public class Organization {

  @Id
  @Column(columnDefinition = "serial", name = "szervezet_azon")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

   @AggregateIdentifier
   @Column(name = "aggregate_azon")
   private String aggregateId;

  @NotEmpty
  @Column(name = "szervezet_nev")
  private String organizationName;

   @CommandHandler
   public Organization(CreateOrganizationCommand command){
   System.err.println("CommandHandler");
   AggregateLifecycle.apply(new OrganizationCreatedEvent(command));
   }

   @EventHandler
   protected void on(OrganizationCreatedEvent event){
   this.id=event.getId();
   this.aggregateId=event.getAggregateId();
   this.organizationName=event.getOrganizationName();
   System.err.println("Eventhandler");
   }

}
```

After i try to run it i got the following exception list:

```
org.axonframework.commandhandling.NoHandlerForCommandException: No handler was subscribed to command [hu.enak.recordrequestingcaseservice.command.CreateOrganizationCommand]
    at org.axonframework.commandhandling.SimpleCommandBus.doDispatch(SimpleCommandBus.java:146) ~[axon-messaging-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.axonframework.commandhandling.SimpleCommandBus.dispatch(SimpleCommandBus.java:111) ~[axon-messaging-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.AbstractCommandGateway.send(AbstractCommandGateway.java:75) ~[axon-messaging-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway.send(DefaultCommandGateway.java:73) ~[axon-messaging-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway.sendAndWait(DefaultCommandGateway.java:90) ~[axon-messaging-4.2.jar:4.2]
    at hu.enak.recordrequestingcaseservice.gateway.service.impl.OrganizationGatewayServiceImpl.createOrganization(OrganizationGatewayServiceImpl.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at hu.enak.recordrequestingcaseservice.controller.query.CaseQueryController.axon(CaseQueryController.java:124) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I dont know why because there is the @CommandHandler. I think its because the @Aggregate annotation is missing, but when i try to put on this and this is the second option i get the following compiler error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-15 10:04:15.199 ERROR 6416 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'organizationRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to use a class as an Axon aggregate, you need to annotate it with `@Aggregate`. In your code, there is no such annotation, causing Axon to not use that class as a command handler.

Axon will also make a Repository for your aggregate, called Repository. It seems from the logs that you already have a repository named that way. They will conflict. You're probably best off renaming the other repository bean, or renaming the Aggregate (which you can do in the `@Aggregate` annotation).

Comment: Ok, so your state stored aggregate example code is not rigth? https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/state-stored-aggregates How is this working?

Comment: The `@Aggregate` annotation is a Spring Stereotype, description which belongs somewhere else then how to define a domain model. The page you are referring to is solely about creating an aggregate's creation, not how to configure it, hence why it is omitted.

Comment: For configuration of Command Models / Aggregates, you should check this page: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/command-processing/command-model-configuration